# Want to find the first instance of each unique string in a Data Frame. Then create a list which marks as first unique instance or not

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

To reword it, I am generating some dummy data.  Assuming a list of customers (some with multiple transactions), I want to mark each Unique Customer.  Then I will generate related Personal Info such as Gender, Customer ID, etc.

My steps were:
  1) Create list of all Unique names
  2) iterate over "Names" column in my Dataframe
  3) when the value in Unique names list and the DataFrame "Names" matches, then append 1 to a list (then delete the name from Unique names list, therefore, creating a 0 for each subsequent instance of the name).  Or leave a 0 if it doesn't match.

I've tried a few methods but none seem to work, this one seemed the closest but I could not find the answer.

## First the DataFrame

```
customers = [ ('jack', 34), 
             ('tom', 30),
             ('jack', 31),
             ('jack', 32),
             ('jon', 16),
             ('tim', 17)  ]
```

## Create a DataFrame object

```
df = pd.DataFrame(customers, columns = ['Name' , 'Age'])
```

## 1) create list of Unique Names

```
uniques = df.Name.unique().tolist()
uniques
```

## 2)

```
worklist = []

for i in df:
    if df["Name"] == uniques[i]:
        worklist.append(i)
        uniques.remove(i)
    else:
        worklist.append(0)

print(worklist)
print(uniques)
```

At the end, I should have a list of dummy variables (1,0s)
　　[1,1,0,0,1,1]
  Similarly, the Unique names list should be empty.

However, I continually get this error.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: What is the expected output for this example ? If I understood well you want to append `1` to your worklist the 1st time you encounter the customer name and `0` for each other time meaning for your example it will look like `1,1,0,0,1,1` ?

Comment: Hi! Yes sorry for missing that. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is because you don't loop over what you think you are looping, when doing your loop you actually loop over the column names ("Name" and "Age") meaning that you ask for `uniques["Name"]` and `uniques["Age"]` which raise the error, list indices are not str.

You can do some kind of switch button using a dict instead of a list for your `uniques` variable:

```
customers = [ ('jack', 34), 
             ('tom', 30),
             ('jack', 31),
             ('jack', 32),
             ('jon', 16),
             ('tim', 17)  ]

df = pd.DataFrame(customers, columns = ['Name' , 'Age'])
uniques = {name: True for name in df['Name']}

worklist = []
for name in df["Name"]:
    if uniques[name]:
        worklist.append(1)
        uniques[name] = False
    else:
        worklist.append(0)

print(worklist)
```

The `uniques` variable is not empty at the end though but filled with keys that are all "False", not sure if its important, if it is then tell me and I'll edit.